How do I make a custom jsonschema keyword (vocabulary) that can be used anywhere in another schema (but draft-07) compatible
I found this interesting question and this is exactly what I am looking for, too.
But my situation is a little bit different: Is there way to add keywords based on the draft-07 meta-schema and how does it look like in this case? I am currently validating json-schema with Visual Studio Code which only supports draft-07, that's why I am asking.
I created a vocabulary schema, I created a dialect schema referencing my vocabulary within the properties section by extending a local copy of draft-07 version. But Visual Studio Code does not validate the meta-schema keywords. Thanks for hints.
I tried the approach based on draft 2020-12 and tried to transfer the approach to the draft-07 standard, but draft-07 has no json-schema vocabularies and $dynamicAnchor keyword.
